# What is the cheapest/simplest way to deliver a camera to the moon?

Tags: rockets, the-moon, spacecraft, communication, escape-velocity

The **primary objective** is this: to deliver a camera to the moon that live streams to Earth throughout the journey AND once it arrives on the moon.

A **bonus** is if it can then move around on the Moon.

An **extra bonus** is if it can return to Earth intact and fully functional.

What are the best methods of achieving this (with current technology, or technology theoretically available in the next 20 years) if you wish to optimise first for lowest financial cost and second for simplest engineering? How hard are they? What obstacles/challenges would one face?

A lot of people mention that the escape velocity from Earth is very high. Is an alternative to sustain upwards acceleration greater than 9.81m/s^2 until the craft reaches the point at which it begins to fall to the Moon (340,000km or so)?

Comment: If you don't require landing on the moon, i.e. just a fly-by, then it's a lot easier. However it's still a challenge to maintain a uninterrupted data link through the entire journey. But China's Chang'e-5 is probably the closest to what you are asking for, although it returned 2kg of moon samples instead of a camera.

Comment: It is a common misconception. You probably imagined that if you pointed the spacecraft towards the Moon and started firing your engines you would eventually get to the Moon? But with a liquid fuel engine, try to imagine fuel consumption when, instead of a several minute burn (to get on a circumlunar trajectory), you will be burning engines for days to go straight to the Moon (at a slower speed).

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Questions need to have the possibility of fact-based answers; we can't solicit options. Different readers will interpret what "easiest" means differently. Can you give some insight into your view of what kinds of things would make one solution "easier" than another?

Comment: @uhoh thanks and yes great point, I have now edited the question.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance by extremely crude calculations you'd need a rocket that could produce enough force to accelerate its mass around 10m/s^2 for 16hrs? (assuming air resistance tapers off significantly relatively quickly)

Comment: Thanks! Based on your comments, it looks like your crunching numbers without any attention to how one generates acceleration in the first place. There's nothing even close to being able to generate "10m/s^2 for 16hrs" that's possible in the near future, much less something that could be considered "easiest". Also, what is it about the way things DO get sent to the Moon that makes one think that they're not already doing it the easiest way?

Comment: Why?  A livestream from the moon would be incredibly boring.  Nothing ever happens there except the very occasional meteorite impact, that will happen too fast to resolve in your livestream.

Comment: @uhoh thanks, info on why you think that isn't possible would be useful to this question. I imagine most current missions are likely to have a more complex objective than merely reaching the moon with a live-streaming camera, hence I wonder: of the possible ways of achieving this, which is cheapest? If you think it is one of the current ways, then stating/explaining that would be useful to this question.

Comment: @gerrit comment appreciated, though that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is an interesting question, however it's extremely broad. Entire space agencies devote years to this sort of project.

Comment: To return the camera to Earth does not make sense, only material from the Moon would be worth the huge cost of a return.

Comment: @GdD thanks and thanks for your comment. In that case, a broad answer may be appropriate. The answer could well address whether X method that modern space agencies commonly use would be cheapest for this particular kind of mission (if such X does exist).

Comment: @Uwe thanks Uwe, comment appreciated. Though that is irrelevant to the question. Suggesting how the camera could be returned along with moon material would however be useful.

Comment: A return of Moon material together with the camera would not make sense.

Comment: @Uwe comment appreciated. Though I suspect it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Easiest: wait for substantial Moon habitation. FedEx a camera to a Moon address.

Comment: @JonCuster forgot to mention that we should optimise for time too in some regard. i.e. **not after our entire generation has passed away**.  P.S. I've now edited the question to address this.

Comment: It’s been alluded to by others, but you should read up on why we traditionally accelerate rockets (mostly) perpendicular to the direction of gravity rather than directly against it.

Comment: Questions which are too broad are off-topic @M.Guillaume.

Comment: You want ~1 g of acceleration for 16 *hours*? Fortunately, that's not necessary to get to the Moon. The burn times of the 3 stages of the classic Saturn V (which sent Apollo to the Moon) are measured in minutes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: I mean, this is pretty much what the CLPS program is, but with more science payloads than just cameras. Suggest you google that NASA program as well as the providers like Intuitive Machines and Astrobotic.

Comment: Earth's escape velocity has nothing to do with what is required to get to the moon (it's roughly half the dV required)